# cellForRowAtIndexPath never been called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know this question been asked before but i haven't found an answer for this particular problem.
i have been followed the apple-tutorial step-by-step but i cant see my data on the table view.

The problem is that the func "cellForRowAtIndexPath" never been called although  numberOfSectionsInTableView return 1 and numberOfRowsInSection also return.

here is my code:

```
#import "StudentListTableViewController.h"
#import "Student.h"
@interface StudentListTableViewController ()



@end

@implementation StudentListTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadInitialData];

    NSLog(@"yes");


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"NUMBERS OF SECTION IN TABLE");
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"NUMBER OF ROWS");

    return self.studentList.count;
}



-(void) loadInitialData
{
    NSLog(@"LOAD INITIAL DATA");
    self.studentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Student* s1 = [[Student alloc] init];
    s1.firstName = @"moses";
    s1.lastName = @"gonzales";
    s1.phoneNumber = @"050-20202020";
    s1.studentID = @"90123456";

   /* Student* s2 = [[Student alloc] init];
    s2.firstName = @"roman";
    s2.lastName= @"wolf";
    s2.phoneNumber = @"050123456789";
    s2.studentID = @"39393939";
    */


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"prototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"fcell");
    // Configure the cell...
    Student* s = [self.studentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = s.firstName;

    return cell;
}
```

Peace :)

Comment: Did you set the dataSource and delegate properties?

Comment: As far as i understand, the dataSource in thiscase is the "studetList"? @tikhop

Comment: And do you ever actually add any data to `studentList`? Because you're not adding any in `loadInitialData`...

Comment: put the debug point on cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `self.studentList` is empty array, therefore it return 0 as count. If `UITableView` has 0 section than it will not call its `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Try to change your `loadInitialData` method.(Add `s1` to the self.studentList).